# How can I get a visa for Canada as a Kenyan citizen visiting the USA?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, kenyan-citizens

I am visiting the USA with a B1/B2 visa, with a Kenyan passport.
Do I need a visa to visit Canada and if I do, what are requirements and the process for me to be able to get a visitor's visa?

Answer (score 2):

Kenyan nationals do normally require a visa to visit Canada.

Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp

To apply for a visa, you must show evidence of your legal status in the territory where you're applying.

Sources:

- http://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_welcome
- http://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_docs_forms_checklists
- http://www.cic.gc.ca/English/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5484E.PDF

In your case, proof of immigration status will be

- the visa you used to enter the US
- the stamp you received when you entered the US, and
- a print-out of your I-94 record, for which you'll need to visit http://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.

Other requirements are substantially the same as for your B1/B2 visa, or indeed for any visitor's visa.  You must have a reasonable purpose for your trip, you must have enough money for your trip, and so on.  These requirements are also covered in the sources cited above.